# Add and remove chatbot script tags in Angular components to only show on certain pages

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to inject a chatbot `<script></script>`in certain of my Angular components, and when the user is about to navigate to a different component/URL, I would like to remove the `<script></script>` (if necessary?).

I had a look at using [Renderer2](http://blog.davidjs.com/2018/09/insert-script-tags-in-angular-components/) and other answers, but as I am only interested in appending a script, and not load a script file, I am not sure how to implement this, or whether these methods would work.

I know due to Angular security reasons, I cannot simply add it to my component HTML, so was thinking of using `ngAfterViewInit()` and `ngOnDestroy()` to inject and remove the script respectively.

**Something like this to add the external script tags:**

```
// Create the element

var script = document.createElement("script");

// Add script markup

script.innerHTML = "<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=7e..."></script>";

// Append

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

I am a bit fuzzy regarding the usage of     `script.innerHTML = "<script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=7e..."></script>"`, and whether I am using it correctly.(?)

**Alternatively, using this (if this would work, how can I add the script id (`id="ze-snippet"`):**

```
  constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const s = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=7e...';
    s.text = ``;
    this.renderer2.appendChild(this.document.body, s);
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my question answered:**

My alternate option above, using Renderer, worked perfectly. I simply had to add my id attribute.

**This is my code with my imports:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-us-page',
  templateUrl: './contact-us-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-us-page.component.scss']
})
export class ContactUsPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const s = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.id = 'ze-snippet';
    s.src = 'https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=7e...';
    s.text = ``;
    this.renderer2.appendChild(this.document.body, s);
  }

}
```

Hope this helps someone else!